# Заполнение div волнистой дорожкой SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Я хочу заполнить `<div>` цветом и добавить тень к границе, но мой код делает только вот так, как  в коде сниппета.
 Мне необходимо получить изображение, как показано на рисунке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg height="125" width="1349">
  <path d="M -35 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 40 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 190 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 265 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 415 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 490 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 640 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 715 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 865 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 940 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1090 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 1165 100 s 75 -125 150 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)" />
  <path d="M 1315 100 s 35 50 75 0" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37301702/7394871

Comment: Это конечно простой топик для перевода, но выбрал я его из-за интересного на мой взгляд приема,- использование `pattern` в этом конкретном примере (**Второй ответ**). Можно взять на вооружение стандартный, казалось бы прием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такая получилась волнишка на CSS:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {height: 100vh; background: url(https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/2560x1024/e/56/puzyri-bulki-zelenyy-green.jpg); background-size: cover;}

.container {
  position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 50vh; margin-top: 50vh;
  background: rgb(255, 195, 56);
}

.wrp {
  position: relative; overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%; height: 80px; top: -80px;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: -100%;
  width: 300%; height: 80px;
  animation: 10s infinite linear wave;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {left: -100%;}
  50% {left: -200%;}
  100% {left: -100%;}
}

.wave::before {
  content: ""; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 60px;
  background-size: 160px 80px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 55px 60px, rgb(255, 195, 56) 48px, transparent 52px), radial-gradient(circle at 55px 56px, gray 30px, transparent 57px);
}

.wave::after {
  content: ""; position: absolute; left: 65px; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 160px 40px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 70px -22px, transparent 45px, rgb(255, 194, 56) 50px), radial-gradient(circle at 65px -45px, transparent 65px, gray 80px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrp"><div class="wave"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Первый ответ:

В вашем коде вы создаете несколько элементов пути, в которых каждый элемент имеет один `subpath` c `curveTo`. Вместо этого вам нужен один элемент `path` с несколькими `subpaths` вместе с `curveTo`.

В вашем сценарии простейшая квадратичная кривая Безье будет работать хорошо.
 После `subpaths` c  `curveTo` вам понадобятся некоторые `subpaths` c `lineTo` для определения области под кривыми.

Например...

```html
<svg height="150" width="880">
  <path d="M 0 100 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0  q 40 -40 80 0 q 40 40 80 0 q 40 -40 80 0 l 0 50 l -880 0 z" stroke="rgb(255, 195, 56)" stroke-width="5" fill="rgb(255, 195, 56)"/>
</svg>
```

### Второй ответ:

Для такой формы вы можете использовать `pattern  svg` и заполнить прямоугольник шириной `pattern`, как показано в следующем примере:

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}
div{
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qi5FGET.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}
svg{display:block;}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>whatever content<br/>with several lines</p>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 60 10">
    <pattern x="-7.5" id="waves" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <path d="M0 10 V5 Q2.5 2.5 5 5 T10 5 V10" fill="#FFC338" />
    </pattern>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" fill="url(#waves)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При помощи svg ты конечно можешь частично добиться нужного результата, но как только у тебя увеличится область экрана твоя svg не будет заполнять всю область. В таких ситуациях, как твоя, лучше использовать canvas. К тому-же тебе не придется заморачиваться с прописыванием всех координат вручную.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw() {
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  let height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, height / 2);
  
  for (let x = 0, amplitude = 30; x < width; x++) {
    let y = Math.sin(x / amplitude * Math.PI / 2) * amplitude;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + height / 2);
  }
  
  ctx.lineTo(width, height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, height / 2);
   
  ctx.fill();
}

draw();

window.addEventListener("resize", draw);
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: не нужно лично обращаться в своих ответах, для этого есть комментарии и ещё один момент по следам ваших слов,- вам что-ли лень было открыть сниппет на "полный просмотр" и убедиться, что svg прекрасно масштабируется

Comment: Я не был бы так самоуверенным. Даже не надо открывать снипет чтоб понять, что у svg фиксированный размер height="125" width="1349"
http://prntscr.com/i92mjf

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72597/discussion-on-answer-by-profesor08--div---svg).